# How to parse line of PDF file from PHP?

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-parsing

I want to parse PDF file from PHP. For this, I have build this code (I have used PDF Parser library).

Code:

```
<?php
     
    // Include Composer autoloader if not already done.
    include 'vendor/autoload.php';
     
    // Parse pdf file and build necessary objects.
    $parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
    $pdf    = $parser->parseFile('XA035 - Luis gui Lopes esteves.pdf');
     
    $text = $pdf->getText();
    echo $text;
?>
```

With this code, I'm able to read the text from PDF file but I'm not able to parse the information because for example, if in the file I have this line:

> PERSONAL INFORMATION Marco Mengoni
>
> Italia
>
> Via della giustizia

when I call my page the  echo $text; print this on the page:

> PERSONAL INFORMATION Marco Mengoni Italia Via Della Giustizia.

Now is there a mode to parse single line????

Comment: just run:

$text = str_replace('\n',' ',$pdf->getText());

Comment: thanks you, but I have change my code, with your code, then when I try to execute echo $text, I can see only one line of text